# Regex to remove pound sign and double commas java csv

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm working with a CSV file that in places, has multiple commas and pound signs. My question is about how to remove the multiple commas and the pound signs, while leaving a single comma between fields.

The part of this task I am on is, using only java and no external libraries to sort through the csv file sort the array by price. I am to input a number as an input parameter and return that number of rows, ordered by price.

What I have currently is around 1000 lines of data that looks like this:

```
18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,
```

I need to remove the double commas and the pound sign, but for the life of me haven't been able to get it to work.

This is the line I am using for the regex.

```
         String currentLine = line.replaceAll("[,{2}|£]", "");
```

This outputs a line which looks like this:

```
100086 Norway Maple WayMadelleGeorgeotmgeorgeotrr@hao13.com417175.60
```

A larger chunk of the code looks like this and by no means is it nearly finished:

```
  public String[] getTopProperties(int n){
    String[] properties = new String[n];
    String file = "data.csv";
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = ",";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

          String currentLine = line.replaceAll("[,{2}|£]", "");

          System.out.println("Current line is: " + currentLine);
            String[] user = currentLine.split(splitBy);
           }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    return properties;
}
```

Issue is it's now removed all the commas and where the price and double commas used to be, they now connect. 
Could use some help finding some regex that keeps a single comma between each field, as well as removing the pound sign.

Comment: I think you need `.replaceAll("(?<!,),,£", "")`. The lookbehind ensures no replacement is made if there are 3 commas followed with a pound sign. Else, why not use `.replace(",,£", "")`?

Comment: If you're dealing with a CSV, it seems obvious that the double comma is in fact representing an empty field. Why remove it? Just read the CSV in and select your cells from there.

Comment: OP wants double commas-pound to result in single-comma no-pound, so the regex replace would be `.replace(",,£", ",")`

Comment: @StephenP Yeah, the question is, why regex? So, it may be either a mere `.replace(",,£", ",")` or `.replaceAll("(?<!,),,£", ",")` (if there must only be 2 commas before pound sign).

Comment: @Shadowsista: do you actually want to remove `,,£` specifically, or do you mean that you don't want either consecutive commas or a £ in the resulting string?

Comment: Multiple comma's then Lire sign: Find `,+£` Replace `,`

Comment: Also tried .replaceAll("(?<!,),,£", ",") and .replace(",,£", ",") as well as replace(",+£", ",") all of them kept the 2 commas and the pound sign

Comment: Agree with all these comments ... it depends more on the _exact_ requirements.

Comment: @Shadowsista Are you sure you check the value of `currentLine` and not `line` after replacement? Also, you have not revealed the real requirement.

Comment: Have edited question to clarify requirements and show a bit more of the code I'm working with

Answer (score 2):

In your regex `.replaceAll("[,{2}|£]", "");` the square-brackets creates a *[character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)*, so this means "replace any characters `,`, `{`, `2`, `}`, `|`, or `£` with *nothing*".

What you really want is to replace the *sequence* `,,£` with a single comma, which would be `.replaceAll(",,£", ",")`

In java *script* this would be...

```js
var line="18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,";
console.log('   original line: ' + line);
console.log('replacement line: ' + line.replace(/,,£/, ","));
```

---

**update**

Converting this to Java as a stand-alone test program to demonstrate that this *does* work, I get the following:

```
public class so50419207
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String input = "18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,";
        String replaced = input.replace(",,£", ",");
        System.out.println("original string: " + input);
        System.out.println("replaced string: " + replaced);
    }
}
```

Running this...

```
$ javac so50419207.java ; java so50419207
original string: 18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,
replaced string: 18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,307018.48,
```

Comment: Both commas and pound sign is still there when I replace my current line with your suggested one of: .replaceAll(",,£", ",");

Comment: Tried to adapt that JavaScript code to work in my Java project, but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this by parsing the CSV file into a 2D array and ignoring the empty column which results from the double comma. Then parsing the currency column is a snap: just ignore the first character.

Comment: It's not false.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the regex `(,,)(£)?` and tested it in ideone : 
Please find the code below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

final String regex = "(,,)(£)?";
final String string = "18,,5 Ramsey Lane,,See,Amerighi,,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,,\n"
     + "18,,5 Ramsey Lane,,See,Amerighi,,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,,\n"
     + "18,5 Ramsey Lane,,See,Amerighi,,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,,\n"
     + "18,,5 Ramsey Lane,,See,Amerighi,,samerighih@trellian.com,,£307018.48,,";
final String subst = ",";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Substitution result: 18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,307018.48,
18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,307018.48,
18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,307018.48,
18,5 Ramsey Lane,See,Amerighi,samerighih@trellian.com,307018.48,
```